# jackson generating an unexpected "new" field

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson, generator

I'm using spring rest and jackson to generate json. For the class country

```
public class Country extends AbstractPersistable<Long> {

    private String name;
    private String code2;
    private String code3;

    public Country() {
    }

    public Country(String name, String code2, String code3) {
    ... 
    }
...
}
```

I get, for example,

```
{
    "id" : 1,
    "name" : "Afghanistan",
    "code2" : "AF",
    "code3" : "AFG",
    **"new" : false**
}
```

For some classes I get an unexpected "new" field always set to false. I suspect it has something to do with the parametrized constructor, but it's just a guess. Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The class `AbstractPersistable` has a public method called `isNew` specified by the interface `Persistable` (the doc [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.3.4.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/domain/AbstractPersistable.html#isNew%28%29)).

You will have to ignore such property if you don't want it in your JSON, for example, using the [annotation](http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.4.0/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/annotate/JsonIgnoreProperties.html) `JsonIgnoreProperties` in your class.